# in `+': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Currently working on a HackerRank problem in Ruby. When I try to compile

```
in `+': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
```

on the following line

```
print  d + double
```

Which I don't understand since none of those two variables is a string.

```
i = 4
d = 4.0
s = 'HackerRank'

# Declare second integer, double, and String variables.
intOne = 12
double = 4.0
string = "is the best place to learn and practice coding!, we get HackerRank is the best place to learn and practice coding!"

# Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.
intOne = gets.chomp
double = gets.chomp
string = gets.chomp
# Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line.
print i + intOne
# Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.
print d + double
# Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line
print s + string
# The 's' variable above should be printed first.
```

Comment: 5 lines above, you assign a `String` to it. So, of course, it's a `String`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must call method `.to_s` on your integer/ float if you want add it to something string

for example:

```
i = 3
b = ' bah '

c = i.to_s + b 
# => '3 bah'
```

or if you have string like this: '3', and you want get from this string integer you must call `to_i` method if you want iteger, `to_f` it you want float

for example:

```
i = '3'
g = i.to_f
# => 3
```

Comment: you must also call `.to_s` on this object before `+`

Answer (score 4):

You have defined `double` two times:

```
double = 4.0  #Float type
double = gets.chomp #String type
```

So, `double` of `String` type has overridden `Float` type.

You have defined:

```
d = 4.0 #Float type
```

So when you do:

```
print d + double  #actually you are doing here (Float + String)
```

Answer (score 2):

`double` is a String due to `gets.chomp`